# Trying to plot a two point boundary value problem numerically

Tags: differential-equations

NDSolve[Epsilon*y'' + 2*y' + Exp[y] = 0, y[0] = 0,
y[1] = 0, Epsilon = [1/20]

This is the equation I am trying to plot but I continue to get an error that says I cannot use 0 as a variable and also one that says Tag Plus is protected. I'm pretty new to Mathematica so any help as to what I'm doing wrong is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from. Please write the equation in $\LaTeX$ form for disambiguation. Also look up the syntax from the documentation where there are plenty of examples.

Comment: @andre314 Yor code isn't complete, `NDSolve[...,y, {t, 0, 1 }]`  missing

Comment: The following works : `ClearAll[y, t]; Epsilon = 1/20; NDSolve[{Epsilon y''[t] + 2 y'[t] + Exp[y[t]] == 0, y[0] == 0,    y[1] == 0}, y,t]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I just have corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

As a start-up aid (see @andre314's helpful comment) try

```
Epsilon = 1/20; 
Y =NDSolveValue[{Epsilon y''[t] + 2 y'[t] + Exp[y[t]] == 0, y[0] == 0,y[1] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 1 }]
Plot[Y[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]